# What is the correct way of obtaining an access token for service principal object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have an API which is registered as a service principal in Azure AD. I'm trying to obtain an access token from a client application and pass that to the API.

As part of the HttpClient request I've added this code (from Microsoft docs):

```
var accessToken = await tokenCredential.GetTokenAsync(
    new TokenRequestContext(scopes: new string[] { ResourceId + "/.default" }) { }
);
```

This works, however it will only work for 24 hours, at which point I have to restart the app services to make it work again. I'm guessing this is because the token has expired and has not retrieved a new one.

I've read somewhere that if the above code is used, expiration and cache for the token needs to be handled manually.

How should I be retrieving these tokens using `Azure.Identity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be service lifetime issue and a dodgy implementation of HttpClient. After switching to IHttpClientFactory, issues now appear to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code snippet, it seems that you're using client credential flow to generate access token (you set the scope as xx/.default), so I think you can add `Azure.Identity` package and using code below to generate access token. Just calling this method to generate token before you wanna calling the api. Code sample extracts from [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/blob/master/2-Call-OwnApi/daemon-console/Program.cs).

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApplication1.Models;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public async Task<string> gettokenAsync() {
            IConfidentialClientApplication app;
            app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("azure_ad_app_client_id_here")
                    .WithClientSecret("client_secret_here")
                    .WithAuthority(new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com"))
                    .Build();

            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            //e.g.  https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "xxxx/.default" };
            result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
            string accesstoken = result.AccessToken;
            return accesstoken;
        }
    }
}
```